# how to use _matchNr function in jmeter

Tags: jmeter-4.0

I have a script. In that one regExvalue like `wId=122,123,124,125...` like that each time that value may be increased or decreased.

I want to use all values in my script. Once complete all come out and going to next iteration and do the same like first ...

How can I use those all values in one iteration? Is there any function to use like matchNr?

I tried with this function `${wId_matchNr}` no use.

Can some one help me how to use this function or is there any other function?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Match. No from your regex to -1. After that add an debug sampler and check the variables.

Comment: I got the values, i want pick those value one by one in loop controller. like wid_machNr=3 wid_1=111, wid_2=222, wid_3=333. i want use this values in loop controller in first loop with wid_1, sencond loop with wid_2 and 3rd loop with wid_3 values. I tried with this function wid_n but not work to pick the values one by one.

Comment: Use the ForEach Controller for that. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter. Also you can use a counter in your loop and acces the variable with `${__V(wid_${Counter})}`

Comment: Please approve this as final answer!

Comment: Simple trick we don't know how to use. I am really thanks to stack overflow to get clarification from over the global.